# How do I handle an ajax request if the endpoint is either json or a new html page?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, redirect

I have an endpoint that will either return a JSON response or a redirect to a different html page depending on the parameters passed to it. JSON is returned for only some cases, so there are cases that will lead to a new html page. I was wondering if there is a way to get the content of the endpoint with an ajax request and then to either modify the existing page if it's a JSON response or otherwise if it's a html page to make it appear as if the page redirected to that page without calling the endpoint twice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just have to call endpoint and look at the response.  If it's meant to be a redirect, it will likely return a 302 response code and contain the redirect URL.  You can then set `window.location` to that URL and the page will redirect there.  If you get the normal 200 response and the datatype is JSON, then you just process the JSON.

If you just log the response code, the headers and the response itself for each type of endpoint call, you should be able to clearly tell the difference so your code can branch accordingly.

For example, here's what a redirect response might look like:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.iana.org/domains/example/
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this (**Two Methods for Handling Cross-Domain Ajax Calls**)

http://devproconnections.com/aspnet/two-methods-handling-cross-domain-ajax-calls